# Rotated Text doesn't render well

Tags: html, css, webkit-transform

I am trying to display text in html using rotate to display it at 45deg (or near enough that)

Unfortunately it just doesn't look good at all. Does anyone know of a way to fix this or maybe a font that renders better when its at 45degs than other fonts?

Example below
http://jsfiddle.net/stevewill61/3WpfP/

CSS for the Banner in the jsfiddle is the following

```
.test:before {
    position: absolute;
    background: #008000;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'Live';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    font-size: 10pt;
    top: 5px;
    left: -20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Here is a picture as requested

http://oi39.tinypic.com/2607ifa.jpg

Comment: Please describe the problem or share a screenshot. For me, the text is diplayed fine on chrome but not rotated on Firefox (probably because of the webkit prefix). Edit : If you add `-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);`, it is also well displayed on Firefox

Comment: Looks fine to me. This is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MJYRs.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding font-smoothing.
I think the biggest problem is the font-size, if you bump up the size 1 more pt it looks much more clear.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

or

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/stevewill61/3WpfP/

And some examples of font-smoothing:
http://maxvoltar.com/sandbox/fontsmoothing/

Comment: Even updated with large font it still doesnt look right... http://jsfiddle.net/stevewill61/3WpfP/2/

Comment: I changed the font to arial, added a shadow and removed the bold. It looks pretty smooth on my screen, though it didn't look too bad to begin with on my machine, though Mac's do have better anti-aliasing. http://jsfiddle.net/BJpj2/ http://i.imgur.com/rkaw9cl.png

Answer (score 0):

Add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the rule

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/3WpfP/5/